# Why would dlopen() return two different handles for same shared library on two different calls?

Tags: android, c++, c, android-ndk, dlopen

In our app, whose source code is so large that I can't figure out exactly what is happening, in logcat logs I see that one `dlopen()` is just called little after other returning the different handle. This is happening in same process id and same thread id.

Here is the log snippet:

```
10-13 09:22:55.582 29607 29673 I SharedLibraryLoader: loadCommonLibrary. dlopen(c++_shared, 1) successful. handle=0x1aeba53028b77b77

10-13 09:22:56.395 29607 29673 I SharedLibraryLoader: loadCommonLibrary. dlopen(c++_shared, 1) successful. handle=0x92f02f27fcc7e8a1
```

In `dlopen()` man page, https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html, it is mentioned that
`If the same shared object is opened again with dlopen(), the same object handle is returned.`.

I suspect some thing is happening in between these two log statements that is leading `dlopen()` to return different addresses. If anybody has faced similar situation before, please let me know what can lead to such behavior.

Comment: Did you validate that exactly the same library loaded, not different ones with the same name for example?

Comment: Same library path is passed in both the calls.

Comment: I am not asking what is passed, I am asking what is loaded

Comment: Just wondering, is it possible that different library can be library loaded if we pass same path to dlopen?

Comment: If you want to find out what is the problem you should look into proper data. Then, when you know actual info you should ask why and how to avoid. Do you use linux?

Comment: @Slava... Thank you for taking time to help me. Actually, I am investigating a crash that is happening in production. I am currently not able to repro issue locally in my set up, but from the logs I have I can see dlopen is returning two different handles. I find this suspicious and wanted to gather more info dlopen. So coming to your question, looking into data is difficult. Will try more to reproduce the issue locally. Until then I may need to build on other's experiences.

Comment: Note that android is almost, but not quite linux. I would check the Android libdl/bionic source code before assuming it returns the same handle twice.

Comment: Is it possible that dlclose is called in between?